# EMGU imshow not displaying image when it is a matrix<float>

Tags: matrix, emgucv

I want to load an image into a Matrix to work with it using EmguCV in C#.
I tried this:

```
Image<Gray, float> img = new Image<Gray, float>(b);
Matrix<float> I = new Matrix<float>(img.Width, img.Height);
img.CopyTo(I);
CvInvoke.Imshow("test", I);
```

note that b is just a Bitmap loaded from a picturebox.

It compiles, but displays an empty window. What would you suggest? (I wanted to work with the Matrix type because the Mat type does not seem to have convenient ways to do matrix operations etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself. You need to use Byte instead of float.